# Paypal adaptive delayed chained payment

Tags: python, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am working in paypal delayed chained payment, i have attached code snippet in that PAY_PRIMARY action type is specified so the scenario the amount of person one and person two to be summed but in my case it takes primary receiver amount not summing secondary receiver amount.

primary reciever amount =10
secondary receiver amount = 5

after redirecting to paypal i am getting on amount 10 to pay,not 15.

I need any ideas , advice from you guys. below my code

```
receivers = []
receivers.append({'amount':amounts, 'email':"egroveqa1@gmail.com",'primary':'true'})
receivers.append({'amount':amounts, 'email':"kavirajan@egrovesystems.com",'primary':'false'})
print receivers
response = paypal.pay(actionType = 'PAY_PRIMARY',
            cancelUrl = "urlofmywebsite",currencyCode = 'USD',
            feesPayer = 'PRIMARYRECEIVER',receiverList = {'receiver': receivers},
            returnUrl = "urlofmywebsite",
            ipnNotificationUrl = "urlofmywebsite",
            errorLanguage = "en_US")
```

i have added example url instead of original url of the website for security issues.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see any issues with it off hand.  May want to open up a ticket with PayPal MTS at www.paypal.com/mts so that we can check the logs to see what we are receiving.  But from what I can see it looks like you are doing it correctly.  If you open up a ticket, just let me know the ticket number.

Comment: Thanks for your feed back here is my support ticket reference number #130426-000421 from paypal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not how chained payments work. You should pay the primary receiver the total amount and what you specify for the secondary receiver will get registered as a payment from the primary receiver.

The money flows like:

`[payer] => [primary receiver] => [secondary receiver]`

The payer will only know about the payment to the primary receiver.